# Regex match using awk for a line starting with a non conforming string

Tags: awk

I have a huge file, I want to only copy from it lines starting with

```
,H|756|F:BRN\
```

but when I do

```
awk  '$1 ~ /^ ,H|756|F:BRN\/' file_1.txt > file_2.txt
```

I get:

> awk: line 1: runaway regular expression /^ ,H|756|F ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The meta-characters in the regex match needs to be properly escaped to achieve what you are trying to do. In Extended Regular Expressions (ERE) supported by `awk` by default `|` has a special meaning to do alternate match, so you need to escape it to deprive it of its special meaning and treat it literally and the same applies for `\`

```
awk '/^,H\|756\|F:BRN\\/' file
```

Also you don't need to use the explicit `~` match on `$1`. For a simpler case like this, a string pattern starting with, the `/regex/` approach is easier to do.

Answer (score 2):

If the file is "huge", you can consider `grep` or `ack` or `ag`, which may bring you better performance.

```
grep '^,H|756|F:BRN\\' input > output
```

grep uses `BRE` as default, so you don't have to escape the pipe `|`. But the ending back-slash you should escape.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I am learning here. I found evidence that grep is faster than awk. Will have to adapt the rest of the code (this was the last a many awk commands). Will probably end up using your answer, but that of @Inian is more related to the title question